# How can I find out the classes which list types belong to?

Tags: list, haskell, instance, typeclass, deriving

How can I find out the classes which  list types belong to?

In https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html says

> data  [a]  =  [] | a : [a]  deriving (Eq, Ord)

and

> Lists are an instance of classes Read, Show, Eq, Ord, Monad, Functor, and MonadPlus.

Why do the two above not agree completely with each other?

Is a list type an instance of `Foldable` class?
If yes, why is that not mentioned in the link above?

Thanks.

Comment: They do `deriving` means Haskell can implement the `Eq` and `Ord` class automatically (this means you do not need to implement these yourself). The others are implemented with an explicit `instance Monad`, etc.

Comment: (1) Do you mean by default  list is not an instance of Monad? If I want it to be, I have to declare that explicitly? (2) Is a list type an instance of Foldable class? If yes, why is that not mentioned in the link above?

Comment: no, it is, it only means that Haskell can implement certain instances for type classes automatically: these are `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Show` and `Read`.

Comment: Thanks. (1) (2) I am not sure what you mean. (3) How can I find out all the classes which a type (e.g. a list type) belong to?

Comment: with `:i` you can find a list of instances.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do the two above not agree completely with each other?

These two statements do *not* conflict at all.

A [`deriving` [Haskell'10 report]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18200011) means that the compiler will *automatically* derive the instance. You thus do not need to define an `instance` clause explicitly. The report also specifies how this automatic instance will look like.

The Haskell report mentions that only a limited number of type classes can be derived automatically:

> *C* is one of `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Show`, or `Read`.

Certain `ghc` extensions allow more automatically derived typeclasses (like `Functor`, etc.).

besides the one that Haskell can derive automatically, you can manually instantiate others with an [`instance` block [Haskell'10 report]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-770004.3.2).

We can for example define `Maybe` ourselves with:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance Functor Maybe where
    fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
    fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

Our `Maybe` type is thus an instance of `Show`, `Eq`, `Ord` and `Functor` here.

In `ghci`, you can use `:i` to find out to which type classes a type belongs, for example:

```
Prelude> :i []
data [] a = [] | a : [a]    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
instance Eq a => Eq [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Monad [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Ord a => Ord [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Read a => Read [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Show a => Show [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
instance Applicative [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Foldable [] -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
instance Traversable [] -- Defined in ‘Data.Traversable’
instance Monoid [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```